# Using LINQ in lists for creating new lists

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have such a code and I want to select all people's name using LINQ and print new list.

```
var dataGroups = new List<Group>
{
    new Group { Manager = "Bob Brown", Task= " Backend", Developers = new List<Developer>() {
        new Developer { Name = "Nikolas Johns", Birthdate = new DateTime(1973, 4, 22)},
        new Developer { Name = "Robert Green", Birthdate = new DateTime(1989, 12, 11)},
        new Developer { Name = "Mary Williams", Birthdate = new DateTime(1996, 3, 10)}
    }},
    new Group { Manager = "Vanessa May", Task = "Frontend", Developers = new List<Developer>() {
        new Developer { Name = "Dao Li", Birthdate = new DateTime(2000, 3, 15)},
        new Developer{ Name = "Zara Kavarska", Birthdate = new DateTime(1981, 6, 19)},
    }},
};
```

I use something like this and I don't get desired result.

```
var devNames = dataGroups.Select(group => group.Developers.Select(developer => developer.Name));
foreach(var name in devNames)
{
    Console.Write(name + "  ");
}
```

Do you know how to tackle this problem? I’m very new to the subject, I’d be grateful for your help.

Comment: "I use something like this and I don't get desired result." So what is the desired result, and what did you get? The more specific you can be, the easier it will be to help you. (It would also help if you'd provide a [mcve] - you've done part of it here, but not really enough for us to just copy/paste/compile/run.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) if you want to project inner sequences and flatten them:

```
IEnumerable<string> devNames = dataGroups
    .SelectMany(group => group.Developers.Select(developer => developer.Name));
```